# Why does electrochemically formed CuO not adhere to the bulk Cu unlike oxide formed through heating?

Tags: electrochemistry

It is my understanding that copper forms an oxide layer upon heating. The colour of the copper depends on the thickness of this layer and can range from reds to purple to green etc.
I have confirmed this by heating a sample and noticed that the oxide layer is robust is 'adhered' to the bulk copper

Separately, I have attempted to form an oxide layer through electrolysis, passing a current from one copper electrode to another via a CuSO4 solution. A black coating (assumed to be CuO) formed around one electrode. However, the CuO does not adhere at all to the bulk material, rubbing away extremely easily, leaving only shiny metal.

Assuming I am indeed forming CuO, why does this not adhere to the bulk in the same way CuO produced by heating does?

Comment: Red/purple colour is due Cu2O, not CuO. Green is CuCO3 . Cu(OH)2.

Comment: @Poutnik - It is my understanding that the blue/red/purple/greenish colours that come from heating are due to the thin film interference effect, and are related to  the thickness of the oxide layer, and not due to the colour of the oxide (or carbonate) itself.

Comment: It is well known copper is covered by cuprous and not cupric oxide. Aside of that, dry thermal formation and wet electrolytic formation are way different circumstances without justification of the same result.